# jQuery owlCarousel drag and drop Firefox issue

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, tinymce-4, owl-carousel-2

I have used [owlCarousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) to display images and have [tinymce 4](http://tinymce.com) as WYSIWIG editor.

I am facing strange issue when I drag image from carousel to tinyMCE WYSIWIG editor in **FireFox 41.0.2**. Instead of just dropping image, it copies div of carousel within which image is enclosed.

Here is owl configuration

```
var owl = $("#extracted-images");
owl.owlCarousel({
  items : 4, //10 items above 1000px browser width
  itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
  itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // 3 items betweem 900px and 601px
  itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
  itemsMobile : false, // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
  touchDrag : false,
  mouseDrag : false,
});
```

**HTML in TinyMCE WYSIWIG after drag and drop**

***Chrome***

```
<p><img src="http://127.0.1.1/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/SXSW-0033.jpg" alt="Sxsw 0033"></p>
```

***Firefox***

```
<div style="width: 137px;" class="owl-item">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="image-list-box">
       <div class="doc-img-box">
        <img alt="Sxsw 0033" src="http://127.0.1.1/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/SXSW-0033.jpg">
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Cifaab/2 in firefox to get more idea.

**NOTE: I have not set `draggable = 'true'` on carousel image tags** But it doesn't change the result even after setting `draggable` it to `true`.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following configuration when initializing tinyMCE.

`invalid_elements: "div"`

Here you need to specifies all the elements which you want to ignore while dropping image in tinyMCE. For more details check documentation [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:invalid_elements)